# Solving a non-linear Partial differential equation $px^5-4q^3x^2+6x^2z-2=0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have to find out the complete integral of :
$$px^5-4q^3x^2+6x^2z-2=0$$
My attempt: Let $$f(x,y,z,p,q)=px^5-4q^3x^2+6x^2z-2$$ 
So, $$f_p=x^5,f_q=-12q^2x^2,f_x=5px^4-8q^3x+12xz,f_y=0,f_z=6x^2$$
Applying Charpit's method:
$$\frac{dx}{x^5}=\frac{dy}{-12q^2x^2}=\frac{dz}{px^5-12q^3x^2}=\frac{-dp}{5px^4-8q^3x+12xz+6px^2}=\frac{-dq}{6x^2q} $$ $$\implies \frac{dy}{-12q^2x^2}=\frac{dq}{-6x^2q}$$ $$\implies q=\sqrt{(y+c)}$$

where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

I don't see here a way to find out $p$. Please help me solve this problem. Even a hint would be much help.

I'll appreciate any help towards it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$x^5z_x-4x^2z_y^3+6x^2z-2=0$

$x^3z_x-4z_y^3+6z-\dfrac{2}{x^2}=0$

$x^3z_{xy}-12z_y^2z_{yy}+6z_y=0$

Let $u=z_y$ ,

Then $x^3u_x-12u^2u_y+6u=0$

$12u^2u_y-x^3u_x=6u$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=6u$ , letting $u(0)=1$ , we have $u=e^{6t}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=12u^2=12e^{12t}$ , we have $y=e^{12t}+y_0=u^2+y_0$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-x^3$ , we have $\dfrac{1}{x^2}=2t+f(y_0)=\dfrac{\ln u}{3}+f(y-u^2)$ , i.e. $u=e^\frac{3}{x^2}F(y-u^2)$ , i.e. $u^2=y-g\left(ue^{-\frac{3}{x^2}}\right)$

Comment: @doraemonpal,it's a nice idea to partially differentiate the given equation but my question is :(1)Won't differentiation of the original equation change the original equation thereby its solutions also?(2)Neglecting(1),how will one further simplify $\dfrac{1}{x^2}=2t+f(y_0)=\dfrac{\ln u}{3}+f(y-u^2)$ to get $z$ because here an arbitrary function $f$ is involved?

Comment: @doraemonpal,can it not be done using Charpit's method?

Comment: The full step of this type of the approach can be found in e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322553. The original equation is still useful, but it can use conveniently only when the solution of the auxiliary equation are easy to find. For this problem, the auxiliary ODE is $\dfrac{1}{x^2}=\dfrac{\ln z_y}{3}+f(y-z_y^2)$ , I don't think it is easy to solve for $z$ .

Comment: ,$z=(2/3)(y+a)^{3/2}+1/9 +1/(3x^2) +be^{1/x^2}$,is the final answer given in my textbook.So clearly it is a complete integral.And the solution I get from your way is general integral so how will I convert general to complete integral??

Comment: How can you actually differentiate an équation, its roots Will change because différentiation changes an équation.

Comment: ,will you please provide me the complete integral?

Comment: ,your method is really awesome,+1.Thanks but please provide the complete integral also.I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To find the complete integral of $$px^5-4q^3x^2+6x^2z-2=0  $$
we can use Charpit's method.
$$ Let~~f(x,y,z,p,q)= px^5-4q^3x^2+6x^2z-2=0 ~ \hspace{35mm}\textbf{(1)}$$
The auxiliary equations are
$$\frac{dx}{f_p}= \frac{dy}{f_q}=\frac{dz}{pf_p+qf_q}=\frac{-dp}{f_x+pf_z}=\frac{-dq}{f_y+qf_z}$$
We have,
$$ f_x = 5px^4-8q^3x+12xz, ~~~f_y=0,~~~f_z=6x^2,~~~f_p=x^5,~~~f_q=-12q^2x^2$$
Computing these values in auxiliary equations we get,
$$\frac{dx}{x^5}= \frac{dy}{-12q^2x^2}=\frac{dz}{px^5-12q^3x^2}=\frac{-dp}{5px^4-8q^3x+12xz+6x^2z}=\frac{-dq}{0+6qx^2}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{dy}{-12q^2x^2}=\frac{-dq}{6qx^2}$$
$$\Longrightarrow dy= \frac{-12q^2x^2 }{-6qx^2} dq = 2q~ dq$$
Integrating both sides we get,
$$\Longrightarrow y+a = q^2 $$ $$\Longrightarrow q = \sqrt{y+a}$$
where, $a$ is an arbitrary constant.
Now substituting the value of $q$ in $\textbf{(1)}$ and solving for the value of  $p$ we get, $$px^5=4q^3x^2-6x^2z+2 $$ $$\Longrightarrow p=\frac{4q^3x^2}{x^5}-\frac{6x^2z}{x^5}+\frac{2}{x^5} = \frac{4(a+y)^\frac{3}{2}}{x^3}-\frac{6z}{x^3}+\frac{2}{x^5}$$
Thus we have obtained the values of $p$ and $q$ as follows,
$$p= \frac{4(a+y)^\frac{3}{2}}{x^3}-\frac{6z}{x^3}+\frac{2}{x^5} \hspace{20mm} q = (a+y)^\frac{1}{2}$$
Substituting values of $p$ and $q$ in $dz=p~dx+q~dy$ we get,
$$dz=\left(\frac{4(a+y)^\frac{3}{2}}{x^3}-\frac{6z}{x^3}+\frac{2}{x^5}\right)  ~dx+ (a+y)^\frac{1}{2}~dy$$
Multiplying by $\displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}$ on both sides we get,
$$\displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}dz=\displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}\left(\frac{4(a+y)^\frac{3}{2}}{x^3}-\frac{6z}{x^3}+\frac{2}{x^5}\right)  ~dx+ \displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}(a+y)^\frac{1}{2}~dy$$
$$\Longrightarrow \displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}dz=\displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}\frac{4(a+y)^\frac{3}{2}}{x^3}~dx-\displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}} \frac{6z}{x^3}~dx+\displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}\frac{2}{x^5}~dx+ \displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}(a+y)^\frac{1}{2}~dy$$
$$\Longrightarrow \displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}dz -\displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}} \frac{6z}{x^3}~dx =\displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}\frac{4(a+y)^\frac{3}{2}}{x^3}~dx+\displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}\frac{2}{x^5}~dx+ \displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}(a+y)^\frac{1}{2}~dy$$
$$\Longrightarrow \left(\displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}dz -z \displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}} \frac{6}{x^3}~dx\right)  =\left(\displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}\frac{2}{x^5}~dx\right) +\left(\displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}\frac{4(a+y)^\frac{3}{2}}{x^3}~dx+ \displaystyle{e^\frac{-3}{x^2}}(a+y)^\frac{1}{2}~dy\right) \hspace{5mm} \textbf{(2)}$$
Put $\displaystyle{\frac{-3}{x^2}}=u$ $\Longrightarrow \displaystyle{\frac{6}{x^3}}dx=du$
Using this substitution in $\textbf{(2)}$ we obtain,
$$\left(\displaystyle{e^u}dz -z \displaystyle{e^u} ~du\right)  =\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-1}{9}ue^u}~du\right) +\left(\displaystyle{\frac{2e^u(a+y)^\frac{3}{2}}{3}}~du+ \displaystyle{e^u}(a+y)^\frac{1}{2}~dy\right)$$
$$\Longrightarrow d(ze^u) = \frac{-1}{9} d \left( (u-1) e^u \right) + \frac{2}{3} d\left( (a+y)^\frac{3}{2} e^u \right)  $$
On integrating we obtain,
$$\Longrightarrow ze^u = \frac{-1}{9} \left( (u-1) e^u \right) + \frac{2}{3} \left( (a+y)^\frac{3}{2} e^u \right) +b $$
$$\Longrightarrow z = \frac{-1}{9} \left( (u-1) \right) + \frac{2}{3} \left( (a+y)^\frac{3}{2} \right) +be^{-u} $$
But $u=\frac{-3}{x^2}$,
$$ \therefore ~~ z = \frac{2}{3} \left( (a+y)^\frac{3}{2} \right) +be^{\frac{3}{x^2}} + \frac{3}{x^2} + \frac{1}{9}  $$

Answer (score 0):

Since $q:=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$, it follows from $q=\sqrt{y+c}$ that
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\sqrt{y+c} \implies z(x,y)=\frac{2}{3}(y+c)^{3/2}+f(x),
\tag{1}
$$
hence
$$
p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=f'(x). \tag{2}
$$
Substituting $z, p,$ and $q$ in the PDE $px^5-4q^3x^2+6x^2z-2=0$, we obtain the following ODE:
$$
f'(x)+\frac{6}{x^3}f(x)=\frac{2}{x^5}. \tag{3}
$$
To solve it, we multiply both sides of $(3)$ by $e^{-3/x^2}$ and integrate the result:
$$
e^{-3/x^2}\left(f'(x)+\frac{6}{x^3}f(x)\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-3/x^2}f(x)\right)=\frac{2}{x^5}e^{-3/x^2}
$$
$$
\implies f(x)=e^{3/x^2}\int\frac{2}{x^5}e^{-3/x^2}dx=\frac{x^2+3}{9x^2}+be^{3/x^2}. \tag{4}
$$
Substituting $(4)$ in $(1)$ we finally obtain
$$
z(x,y)=\frac{2}{3}(y+c)^{3/2}+\frac{x^2+3}{9x^2}+be^{3/x^2}. \tag{5}
$$

Answer (score -2):

From given pde and by using the value q, we get 
$P=\frac{4(y+c)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{x^3}-\frac{6z}{x^3}+\frac{2}{x^5}$
and subtitute the values $p$ and $q$ in $Z=pdx+qdy$ and use multiplier $e^{-\frac{3}{x^2}}$ 
and on integration we get complete required complete integral